# Derivation of attenuator noise factor as a function of its physical temperature

Tags: noise, signal-to-noise, attenuator

I have been struggling for the past few days with the noise analysis of an attenuator of attenuation \$l\$, at a temperature \$T_A\$, connected to a source with input noise temperature \$T_0\neq T_A\$. Consider an antenna with equivalent noise temperature \$T_0\$ connected to an attenuator held at temperature \$T_A\$.

I know that, when \$T_A=T_0\$, the noise factor of the attenuator is equal to its loss \$f=l\$, although I have not seen a derivation of that I could fully understand either.

When \$T_0\neq T_A\$, that becomes even more difficult. The closest to a rigorous derivation I have found is in [here](https://reeve.com/Documents/Noise/Reeve_Noise_3_AttenAmpNoise.pdf). However, it casually wields concepts like thermal equilibrium and impedance matching, whose implications in noise analysis I cannot quite understand.

I have searched for books and research papers to no avail. I have also read several questions here which have clarified some concepts qualitatively, but what I am looking for is an in-depth discussion.

Any comments/reference suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Start with something simple, a source at temperature \$T\$ has an available noise power \$kT/Hz\$.  Pass this through a noiseless attenuator with attenuation \$l\$, with \$0 < l < 1\$ and \$l\$ is a power ratio, then at the output of the attenuator, the available noise power is the attenuated source power, \$lkT\$ (we'll drop the \$/Hz\$).

Now for a real attenuator which is also at \$T\$, the available noise at the output is still \$kT\$ (it is no different to  the original source), so you can work out how much noise power an attenuator with attenuation \$l\$ at temperature \$T\$ adds.

Using the definition of noise figure

\$F = \frac{Total Output Noise Power}{Output Noise Power from Source alone}\$

with the source at \$T_0\$ and the attenuator at \$T_A\$, and you should be able to take it from here..

**Edit:**
All passive components that are not pure reactances have the same available noise power when at the same temperature.  To see this, take a component at temperature T, place an ideal matching network to a simple resistor at the same temperature. As they are matched, the available noise power from the resistor is dissipated in the component, and the available noise power from the component is dissipated in the resistor. The available noise power (per Hz) from the resistor is \$kT\$ and thermodynamics tells us that there is no net power flow between two passive components at the same temperature, hence all passive components that are not pure reactances, have an available  noise power of \$kT\$.   (You actually match it at each frequency and use an ideal filter to show that the noise is the same at all frequencies).

Your attenuator at T,  with the matched source at T at the input, produces the same noise at the output as the source at T produces at its output.

Comment: I agree with your first paragraph (although, the way you used \$l\$, I would call it a gain and not an attenuation).

However, I cannot follow the rest of the answer. You say the output noise level of the attenuator should be the same as that of the original source. I know that to be true, but I don't know how to justify it.

Furthermore, if I understand correctly, you later suggest that I use the same reasoning with the source at \$T_0\$ and the attenuator at \$T_A\$. Does this mean that I should consider the attenuator output noise level to by \$kT_A\$? I don't think that is true.

Comment: thank you for your response and later edit. I am not sure that is the case in your example but, in this case, the component is a two-port network. You match the input or output to a resistor but, what do you do with the other port? Unless you leave it open, the noise power from the resistor can either be dissipated in the component or pass through it.

On the other hand, how would you analyse the case where the source and component temperatures are different?

It might seem I am trying to find flaws in your reasoning, but I am just trying to understand it.

Comment: Feed your attenuator (at T) from a matched source (at T). This combination is a one-port passive component at temperature T, so you know the output  noise. As the source is matched you can apportion this output noise  to the source and attenuator, so you  know the noise added by your attenuator when it is at T.

This analysis assumes that the attenuator is matched, if it isn't then you are in the realm of circuit analysis (or noise circles), and there is no single noise figure of your attenuator.

Comment: Ok. I understand that, thank you. Now, how would you go about analysing the case where the attenuator and the source are at different temperatures? How would your reasoning "thermodynamics tells us that there is no net power flow between two passive components at the same temperature" apply in that case?

Comment: Now that you know how much noise comes out of the attenuator when both it and the source are at \$T_A\$, you can use the fact that it is an attenuator and is matched, to work out how much of this noise is from the attenuator and how much is from the source.  Then when the source is at \$T_0\$ you simply scale the source component of the noise.  Use the definition of the noise figure I gave to work out the noise figure of the attenuator at \$T_A\$.

Comment: Ok, so you just assume the internal noise generated by the attenuator does not depend on its input signal, only on its physical temperature. Why does the fraction of input power that is dissipated in the attenunator not affect the internal noise power it generates? I suppose that power would tend to increase the temperature of the attenuator, but it can't, because the attenuator is cooled.

Comment: Sounds like you have the right idea now.  Don't forget that at the source/attenuator interface that noise power flows both ways as well.  If they are both at the same temperature then the flows are equal, otherwise there is a net flow from the hotter to the colder as there should be.

Comment: There is where I start to get lost. I don't quite understand terms like "thermal equilibrium" in this context and I don't know how to analyse the power flows between components due to thermal gradients. Actually, I cannot even justify why the flows should be equal when they are at the same temperature. That exceeds my knowledge as an electrical engineer and I would like to delve into it. I don't mean to further exploit you, I am grateful for your patience. That is why I initially asked for a reference that discusses this topic in depth, but also starting from the basics.

Comment: I don't know your background, but if you want to understand noise analysis you do need some thermodynamics. I'd suggest either a good physics text, or searching for some thermodynamics course notes in the .edu domain, and try to find some that start at your level. If you like videos, possibly an MIT online course.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into your suggestions. The problem with pure thermodynamic courses/texts is that they will probably cover a much broader field than I need just for noise analysis. That is why I was looking for a book covering noise, but from that perspective. Nevertheless, I will continue to look for a reference that loosely matches my needs. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> when TA=T0, the noise factor of the attenuator is equal to its loss f=l ...

This kind of [demonstration](https://analog.intgckts.com/noise-figure-of-attenuator/) ?

Or in this [reference](https://reeve.com/Documents/Noise/Reeve_Noise_3_AttenAmpNoise.pdf) , figure 3-7?

Comment: Yes, I already saw that reference. However, it includes statements like " Under the assumption that the attenuator is in thermal equilibrium, no heat flows out on the attenuator due to temperature gradient". Like I replied to @Tesla23 above, I am looking for a reference that analyses this in depth, but starting with the basics.